# Playstation Plus - Will different account subscription activate locked games?

Tags: psn, ps4, playstation-plus

I bought PlayStation 4 a year ago which was also my first PlayStation. My friend recommended that I should have two accounts.

1. UK Account for playing games with PlayStation Plus subscription.

   - Already have multiple free games.
2. US Account to buy games from the store.

   - Already bought few games.

This question seems like a duplicate but I didn't find a Q/A that specific.

Question:
Now my UK account's Plus membership has expired. I don't see why I should keep both the accounts. I'm wondering... 
**If I will buy Plus membership for my US account, will that unlock my previously 'owned' games I got through the UK account?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Content licenses are bound to the account that activated them. Once the PSN+ account laps, it defaults to a standard PSN account, the free games that were licensed would then be invalid on that system for all accounts. But, any games you had actually purchased, even at a discount price would still be available for all accounts (unless you also removed the account from the system).

The only way to be able to play those games again would be to either renew your subscription to the account that originally downloaded them, or just buy them under the alternate account.

Specifically in regards to your question though. Any "free" games that you downloaded on your UK profile would have to be re-purchased by the US profile to re-aquire them. The only way you would be able to have them free for the US profile is if you had also had a paid US account concurrent to your UK account and had activated the game when (or if) it had been available for that account.

I know you may think this is stupid but remember, the free games are a perk for paid subscribers for that region. If you no longer subscribe to that region then you are no longer eligible for the perks.

Comment: I was actually just about to as about games brought through PS+. just to confirm, if the subscription expires you can still downloaded paid games from that same account without renewing the subscription? you only need to renew the subscription to re-download free games?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If you delete a paid for game (even if you paid a PSN+ discounted price), that game can be re-downloaded on the authorized system for as long as it is still available from the store. Free content will no longer be accessible after the PSN+ membership ends (unless you pay for it directly). You can always look at the "Information" on any download and if it shows an "Expires" date then it is subject to you maintaining your membership. If there is no expiration date then you should be good.